# How to change this useffect to class component in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to change the useEffect, useState to class component but I could not achieve it. Here trying to do a dropdown picker with multiple select options. I'm new to react-native. Any help much appreciated pls.

I have been trying to use the react-native-element-dropdown NPM package which is in the functional component. Now trying to change from functional component to class component.

Here is the code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
 import {Dropdown, MultiSelect} from 'react-native-element-dropdown';

const data = [
{label: 'Item 1', value: '1'},
 {label: 'Item 2', value: '2'},
{label: 'Item 3', value: '3'},

 ];

const DropdownScreen = _props => {
const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(null);
 const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

const _renderItem = item => {
 return (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.textItem}>{item.label}</Text>
    <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('./assets/tick.png')} />
  </View>
   );
 };

  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <Dropdown
    style={styles.dropdown}
    data={data}
    search
    searchPlaceholder="Search"
    labelField="label"
    valueField="value"
    placeholder="Select item"
    value={dropdown}
    onChange={item => {
      setDropdown(item.value);
      console.log('selected', item);
    }}
    renderLeftIcon={() => (
      <Image style={styles.icon} source={require('./assets/account.png')} />
    )}
    renderItem={item => _renderItem(item)}
  />

  <MultiSelect
    style={styles.dropdown2}
    data={data}
    labelField="label"
    valueField="value"
    placeholder="Select item"
    search
    searchPlaceholder="Search"
    value={selected}
    onChange={item => {
      setSelected(item);
      console.log('selected', item);
    }}
    renderItem={item => _renderItem(item)}
     />
    </View>
    );
  };

  export default DropdownScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the whole component; (used icons instead of your images just for demo);

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dropdown, MultiSelect } from 'react-native-element-dropdown';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { IconButton } from 'react-native-paper';

const data = [
  { label: 'Item 1', value: '1' },
  { label: 'Item 2', value: '2' },
  { label: 'Item 3', value: '3' },
];

class DropdownScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dropdown: null,
    selected: []
  }


  _renderItem = (item) => {
      <View>
        <Text>{item.label}</Text>
        <IconButton icon="account" size={20} />
      </View>
  };

render() {

  return (
    <View>
      <Dropdown
        data={data}
        search
        searchPlaceholder="Search"
        labelField="label"
        valueField="value"
        placeholder="Select item"
        value={this.state.dropdown}
        onChange={(item) => {
          this.setState({dropdown: item.value});
          console.log('selected', item);
        }}
        renderLeftIcon={() => <IconButton icon="eye" size={20} />}
        renderItem={(item) => this._renderItem(item)}
      />

      <MultiSelect
        data={data}
        labelField="label"
        valueField="value"
        placeholder="Select item"
        search
        searchPlaceholder="Search"
        value={this.state.selected}
        onChange={(item) => {
          this.setState({selected: item});
          console.log('selected', item);
        }}
        renderItem={(item) => this._renderItem(item)}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
}

export default DropdownScreen
```

Note the changes;

1. first i defined a state.
2. to access the state `this.state.state_key`.To change the state `this.setState({state_key: new_value})`
3. `_renderItem` is not a function now but a method on this class. So to access it, use `this._renderItem()`
4. And at the end we need `render` method to render things.

Comment: For the sake of learning, please comment the reason also for the downvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(null);` as: `this.state= {dropdown: null}`

`setDropdown(item.value);` as : `this.setState({dropdown: item.value})

Comment: it should be `this.state = {dropdown: null}` and not `this.state: {dropdown: null}`